# A conceptual explanation for a simple fact about twists of objects with abelian automorphism group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-cohomology, galois-descent

Suppose $X,X'$ are two objects (say, genus 1 curves) over a field $k$ such that over the algebraic closure $X_{\overline k} \cong X'_{\overline k}$ and moreover, $Aut_{\overline k}(X)$ is abelian.

Then, one can check easily that $Aut_k(X) = Aut_k(X')$. This is not true if the automorphism group is not abelian. Is there a conceptual reason as to why this should be true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Galois group $G$ acts on the classifying space $BAut_{\bar k}(X)$. The set of isomorphism classes of possible choices of $X'$ is $\pi_0$ of the space $(BAut_{\bar k}(X)^{hG}$ of homotopy fixed points for this action, and $Aut_k(X')$ is the fundamental group of the same space. If $Aut_{\bar k}(X)$ is abelian, then the space $BAut_{\bar k}(X)$ is a group and $G$ acts by group homomorphisms, so $(BAut_{\bar k}(X)^{hG}$ is also a group, and therefore its fundamental groups at different points are isomorphic.

Comment: I am not too familiar with homotopy quotients so can you expand a bit (or point to a reference)  on why the homotopy quotient being a group implies that the fundamental group is independent of the path?

Comment: Suppose you have a group $G$ and a point $x$, then multiplication by $x$ induces a homotopy equivalence $G\to G$, and so it induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(G,e)\to \pi_1(G,x)$

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks a lot! @MaximeRamzi

Comment: But this is a homotopy fixed-point space, not a homotopy quotient (=homotopy orbit space). Also, by the way, these are abelian groups.